# History of 12 Teveis

Tags: jewish-date-series, history, calendar

****Looking for answers as to what happened in Jewish history on this date. It can include both positive and negative occurrences. It can also include birthdays or Yarzheits of well known personalities that happened on this date.**

**Please cite / link your sources, if possible.**

**All interesting answers will be up voted.**

***Best answer will be accepted.*****

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)Yechezkial said Nevuah about the fall of Egypt and the triumph of Bavel, 587 b.c.e.

2)A earthquake hit Eretz Yisrael seriously damaging the walls of Yerushalayim and Tower of David, 1033.

3)Mordechai and Esther (of Medzibezh) saved the Jews from Chmielnicki's army, 1648.